# I was trying the html files in my macbook, but when i run and debug it with visual studio code it doesn't work as it supposed to. what should i do?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, macbookpro

I was trying the html files in my macbook, but when i run and debug it with visual studio code it doesn't work as it supposed to. what should i do?

[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gN4w.jpg)

```
<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>
```

this is my code

can anyone help me with it?

Comment: did you forgot the `.html`

Comment: File Extension change using .html